# Which file does caffe execute when doing convolutional operation?

Tags: conv-neural-network, caffe, convolution, pycaffe

There are three files related to convolution in `caffe\src\layers`:`conv_layer.cpp`,`conv_layer.cu`,`cudnn_conv_layer.cpp`.Which file does caffe excute when executing convolutional operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CPU implementation:

```
./src/caffe/layers/conv_layer.cpp
```

For CUDA GPU implementation:

`./src/caffe/layers/conv_layer.cu`